# Llamado de un programa desde otro en Python

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

Tengo un programa en Python y utilizo Tkinter para la parte gráfica. Desde allí creamos un menú y uno de ellos llama un reporte que lo que hace es crear una hoja y mostrarla en PDF.

Mi problema es que ejecuto la primera vez el menú y funciona perfectamente, pero luego no vuelve a abrir el PDF una segunda vez. No muestra ningún error.

La importación desde el programa principal se hace en una función que solo tiene la instrucción: import nombreSubPrograma

Comment: No entiendo bien tu duda. Pero una vez que importas un modulo y este ejecuta su código, importarlo de nuevo no va a ejecutar nada. Te recomiendo pasar esa parte del modulo que esperas que se ejecute más de una vez a una función y hacer elmodulo.funcion() cuando necesites ejecutarlo.

Comment: @DanteS. Creo que me has entendido perfectamente. Podrías explicarme por qué al "importarlo de nuevo no va a ejecutar nada" ??

Comment: Python importa los modulos una vez sola. Si el modulo ya fue importado, no lo vuelve a importar. Se puede forzar el que se vuelva a importar, pero no lo recomiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el problema sea que estás abriendo el archivo PDF en modo solo lectura. Cuando abres un archivo en modo solo lectura, no puedes modificarlo ni guardar los cambios que hayas hecho.

Para abrir el archivo PDF en modo lectura y escritura, debes usar la opción "w+" en lugar de "r" al usar la función open(). Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

with open("nombre_del_archivo.pdf", "w+") as f:
# código para escribir en el archivo

Comment: Saludos, antes de responder a una publicación asegúrate siempre de que se ajuste a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no necesariamente todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas ya que muchas "como ésta" carecen de información como para responderla de forma correcta y lo más seguro es que terminen cerradas, lo más correcto en este caso hubiera sido pedir más información sobre su problema al usuario que realizó la pregunta. ;)